# How to rank price list of different automobile variant in google featured snippet results?

Tags: seo, google, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

We have an automobile pricing website. We want to show prices of all variants of cars in the featured snippet query. For example, if someone types "bmw x3 price" in google search, we want to show prices of all variants OR atleast some pricing information in the featured snippet.

How can I modify my prices HTML to rank in the featured snippet? Would putting prices in the table structure i.e. tr td format help us?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a BMW X3 variant price list type page with an HTML table of pricing for all the variants, this looks like a product page. This might help you come up on search results like this - 
[image]

- So you will have a page for BMW X3 that contains a table of all the variants and will list BMW X3 as a product with a price range (this price range can be used in markup). This page will show up when user searches only for BMW price range or BMW price range. See example below - 
  [image]
- Create child pages for all the variants.
- Use 'Product' Markup on each page so that it shows snippet for individual variants as well. [Link to product markup guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)
- Ensure that you have detailed content in and around the table, only markup and tables don't help. Google picks up the relevancy and context of the content in the tables as well.

If other URL is already featuring in the snippet, the competition might be a bit stiff. Because based on the experience, snippet feature usually get updated every quarter or so, so not that frequent and you might have to wait out a bit.

Comment: you are suggesting that unless we have dedicated variant page, google won't rank us in rich snippet?

Comment: @maverick I am suggesting the best practices that you can follow, what Google can do is not upto us. This structure helps Google understand your site structure and is also good for the users to navigate. Makes sense?

Comment: Agreed. The only problem is that most of variants pages of same model will have exactly the same content (there would be few exceptions where variants vary extensively). Should we create duplicates pages for such things? Problem is 1) how useful those would be for users 2) we might get duplicate content penalty

Comment: Think in terms of specs and the variations you can show,  I am assuming most of them would be in tabular format and not paragraph content, apart from the description one..